# Cannot find device to restore google data and settings

Tags: restore, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, google-backup

I am trying to restore my google account on a new device but it cannot find any of my previous devices under
"Restore your apps and data from one of these devices"

I verified that my old devices have been backing up to google. Not sure how to get them to appear.